# Laravel 5 routing not working when using slashes inside groups?

Tags: url-routing, laravel-5

I am facing a little weird problem with a simple routing in Laravel 5. Below, I have to commented code snippets.

```
// It works when I call /tribut.updateStatus URL
$router->group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'isLogged|isAdmin'], function ($router) {
    $router->resource('tribut', 'Admin\TributController');
    $router->get('tribut.updateStatus', 'Admin\TributController@updateStatus'); 
});

// Does not work when I call: /tribut/updateStatus URL
$router->group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'isLogged|isAdmin'], function ($router) {
    $router->resource('tribut', 'Admin\TributController');
    $router->get('tribut/updateStatus', 'Admin\TributController@updateStatus'); 
});
```

I want to use the second route option. Is it possible? What am I doing wrong? When I call the routing that does not work, the screen goes blank. No error is shown,  neither in log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$router->resource('tribut')` registers a route that caches everything with `GET tribut/*` because it thinks `*` is an id.

The solution is pretty simple, just define the explicit get route **before** the resource route:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'isLogged|isAdmin'], function ($router) {
    $router->get('tribut/updateStatus', 'Admin\TributController@updateStatus');
    $router->resource('tribut', 'Admin\TributController');
});
```